# Django models not returning property value

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm making an API with DRF and now still making database but i got a problem with a field from models.py

my script of `models.py`

```
class Inflasi(models.Model):
sandang = models.FloatField(null=True)
sembako = models.FloatField(null=True)
perumahan = models.FloatField(null=True)
kesehatan = models.FloatField(null=True)
transportasi = models.FloatField(null=True)
informasi = models.FloatField(null=True)
rekreasi = models.FloatField(null=True)
pendidikan = models.FloatField(null=True)
penyedia_pangan = models.FloatField(null=True)
perawatan_pribadi = models.FloatField(null=True)
total_inflasi = models.FloatField(null=True)
tanggal = models.DateField(null=True)

@property
def total_inflasi(self):
    return self.sandang + self.sembako + self.perumahan + self.kesehatan + \
        self.transportasi + self.informasi + self.rekreasi + \
        self.pendidikan + self.penyedia_pangan + self.perawatan_pribadi

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.tanggal)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Inflasi"
    verbose_name_plural = "Inflasi"
```

and that not return the property value in Django admin dashboard

and this my `admin.py` script

```
@admin.register(Inflasi)
class InflasiModelAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    class Meta:
        model = Inflasi
        fields = '__all__'
```

this my view

[image: API View]

what must i do for fix that?

Answer (score 2):

you will have to use `list_display` attr. of the ModelAdmin where you need to specify the method name that you have declared on the model

Reference:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display

```py
@admin.register(Inflasi)
class InflasiModelAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('total_inflasi', 'tanggal', ...)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Inflasi
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: The property models still not displaying in API view like the post was edited